# How to set allocator for dynamically allocated stl container?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, tbb

I am using TBB custom memory allocator.

```
tbb::memory_pool<std::allocator<char>> shortTermPool;
typedef tbb::memory_pool_allocator<Result*> custom_allocator;
std::vector<Result*,custom_allocator>* results =(std::vector<Result*,custom_allocator>*)shortTermPool.malloc(sizeof(std::vector<Result*,custom_allocator>));
```

The issue is that setting the allocator is in the constructor. Malloc doesn't call the constructor. The default usage would be something like this:

```
tbb::memory_pool<std::allocator<char>> shortTermPool;
typedef tbb::memory_pool_allocator<Result*> custom_allocator;
std::vector<Result*,custom_allocator> results (custom_allocator(shortTermPool));
```

Is there a way to do a malloc of the stl container, and then afterward assign a custom allocator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After doing this:

```
std::vector<Result*,custom_allocator>* results = (std::vector<Result*,custom_allocator>*)shortTermPool.malloc(sizeof(std::vector<Result*,custom_allocator>));
```

You will need to use *placement-new* to construct the object:

```
new(results) std::vector<Result*,custom_allocator>(custom_allocator(shortTermPool));
```

---

Though, doing something like this below is perhaps more readable:

```
using MemoryPool = tbb::memory_pool<std::allocator<char>>;
using CustomAllocator = tbb::memory_pool_allocator<Result*>;
using CustomVector = std::vector<Result*, CustomAllocator>;

MemoryPool shortTermPool;
void* allocatedMemory = shortTermPool.malloc(sizeof(CustomVector);
CustomVector* results = static_cast<CustomVector*>(allocatedMemory);
new(results) CustomVector(CustomAllocator(shortTemPool));
```

---

**EDIT**

Remember **not** to use `delete` on the pointer since the memory it points to wasn't allocated by `new`; and remember to explicitly destruct the object like this:

```
results->~CustomVector();
```

More completely:

```
MemoryPool shortTermPool;
void* allocatedMemory = shortTermPool.malloc(sizeof(CustomVector);
CustomVector* results = static_cast<CustomVector*>(allocatedMemory);
new(results) CustomVector(CustomAllocator(shortTemPool));

/* Knock yourself out with the objects */

/*NOTE: If an exception is thrown before the code below is executed, you'll have a leak! */

results->~CustomVector();
shorTermPool.free(results);

//Don't do
//delete results
```

You may also want explore the use of smart pointers with custom deleters to handle the proper destruction and freeing of memory gotten from `tbb`'s memory allocators

Comment: Can one use C++11 uninitialized storage with custom allocators in this fashion?